# Which software is used to design this Cirucit?

Tags: pcb-design, design

Could you help me with the name of the software used to design the circuit below?

I have used Eagle (Easily Applicable Graphical Layout Editor) but I want to design my circuits with looks something like this below.

[image: http://www.waitingforfriday.com/images/f/f0/PICDEM_FS_USB.png]

Comment: Eagle has a schematic editor as a separate package: http://www.cadsoftusa.com/eagle-pcb-design-software/schaltplan-editor/?language=en

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The software is [ExpressPCB](http://www.expresspcb.com/ExpressPCBHtm/Free_cad_software.htm). This software includes two applications called ExpressPCB and ExpressSCH, one for drawing schematics, the other for PCB layout.

The original post of this image is [this](http://www.waitingforfriday.com/index.php/PIC_USB_Development_Board), and in the end of the post the Author says what software he used.

> In the following zip file you will find the schematics in ExpressSCH
>   format and also the PCB artwork in ExpressPCB (both pieces of software
>   can be freely downloaded from the Internet):

Comment: Thank you so much. I actually lost the track of actual post and other posts mixed up with each other. Thanks for solving my problem. :)